# Using the the right word(s)

Tags: grammar

I want to say "the image is magnify-able after ...."

> a) click.
>
> b) clicked.
>
> c) clicking.
>
> d) being clicked.

Which of the above options is more correct? I pick (d).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be (d). You could also say,

> The image is magnify-able after it is clicked.

If you said (b) people would still understand you well.

Answer (score 0):

None, really.  "Magnify-able" is a *property* of the element, and "clickable" is another property of the element.  You don't click to *make* it magnify-able, since it already *is* magnify-able.  Instead you click to *magnify* it:

> The image is *magnified* (when you click on it / on being clicked).

Another way to say this is "zoom in":

> You can click to zoom in on the image.